# Gerar Pdf via ajax.POST com Rotativa

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, rotativa

Quero gerar um arquivo .pdf usando Rotativa, minha chamada ajax é a seguinte:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home/Index",
                    data: { nome: inputName, laudos: laudos, imagem: imgSelecionada },
                });
```

E o código na Action é esse:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(UsuarioViewModel user)
    {
        string header = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Header2.html");
        string footer = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Footer.html");

        string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html \"{0}\" " +
                                              "--header-spacing \"0\" " +
                                              "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                                              "--footer-spacing \"5\" ", header, footer);

        var pdf = new ViewAsPdf
        {
            ViewName = "Modelo",
            Model = user,
            CustomSwitches = customSwitches
        };


        return pdf;
    }
```

É realmente possível fazer algo desse tipo ou devo usar outra abordagem? Depois de muito pesquisar, vi em alguns lugares que o Rotativa não trabalha muito bem com requisições ajax.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que o problema ocorre pelo fato da biblioteca original wkhtmltopdf não ser capaz de resolver a requisição feita com Ajax, com os seus respectivos callbacks.

Em resumo, a rotativa não consegue suportar chamadas ajax.

Vejo que essa afirmação se repete tanto no aqui stackoverflow quanto em issues abertas da biblioteca.

Porém, temos como contornar o problema de maneira simples.

Fazendo a substituição da chamada Ajax por:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");

form.method = "post";
form.action = "Home/Index";
form.setAttribute("target", "ViewIndex");

var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "json");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "pData");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify({ nome: inputName, laudos: laudos, imagem: imgSelecionada }));

form.appendChild(hiddenField);

document.body.appendChild(form);
window.open('', 'ViewIndex');

form.submit();
```

Em seguida, alterando o seu método no controller da seguinte maneira:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic Index(string pData)
    {
    var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsuarioViewModel>(pData);

    string header = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Header2.html");
    string footer = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/Footer.html");

    string customSwitches = string.Format("--header-html \"{0}\" " +
                                          "--header-spacing \"0\" " +
                                          "--footer-html \"{1}\" " +
                                          "--footer-spacing \"5\" ", header, footer);

    return new ViewAsPdf
    {
        ViewName = "Modelo",
        Model = user,
        CustomSwitches = customSwitches
    };
}
```